# Searching for mp3 files without matching cdg file

Tags: search, file-search

I use Windows 10, and have about 15,000 mp3's in one folder, some of which have matching cdg's that show lyrics.  I would like to search the folder to find mp3's which **DO NOT** have matching cdg files and remove them.

For example,  I might have crazy.mp3 and crazy.cdg, in a folder with crazed.mp3.  I would like to keep crazy.mp3 and crazy.cdg but delete crazed.mp3

Comment: Which operating system?  Which shell?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show an example of the file names you have and which files should be removed.